# Mapbox bindPop with external result list

Tags: javascript, dom, mapbox

I am using Mapbox to plot location data on a map while also displaying the information in a list below the map. Clicking one of the results in the list should open the corresponding marker popup window on the map. I also have a need for the ability to tie javascript functions to links within the popup. I believe I have it working but the main issue I have now is that when you click a result listing, it opens on the map but is then removed from the DOM.

I've put together a jsfiddle to illustrate my issue. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. http://jsfiddle.net/jvitelli/7BNC5/4/

```
var map = L.mapbox.map("testMap");
var layerGroup;


//set up the map and center it based on the user.    
map.addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer("examples.map-i86nkdio", {
    detectRetina: true
}));

map.zoomControl.setPosition('topright');
map.setView([40.7348522, -73.9910852], 15);

var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer();
featureLayer.setGeoJSON(response.results);

layerGroup = L.layerGroup();
layerGroup.addLayer(featureLayer);
layerGroup.addTo(map);

var resultSet = document.getElementById("results");

featureLayer.eachLayer(function (marker) {

    var d = document.createElement("div");
    var aTitle = document.createElement("a");
    aTitle.innerHTML = marker.feature.properties.title;
    aTitle.id = marker.feature.properties.id;
    aTitle.onclick = function (e) {
        alert(marker.feature.properties.title);
        map.panTo(marker.getLatLng());
        marker.openPopup();
        return false;
    };
    var address = document.createElement("p");
    address.innerHTML = marker.feature.properties.address + "<br />" + marker.feature.properties.city + ' ' + marker.feature.properties.state + "<hr />";

    d.appendChild(aTitle);
    d.appendChild(address);
    resultSet.appendChild(d);

    //bind the same content to the info window.                
    marker.bindPopup(d, {
        autoPan: true,
        autoPanPadding: L.point(40, 40),
        closeButton: true
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the same HTML elements for the tooltip and for the off-map content. Here's an example that fixes this: http://jsfiddle.net/7BNC5/6/

```
function makeDiv() {
var d = document.createElement("div");
var aTitle = document.createElement("a");
aTitle.innerHTML = marker.feature.properties.title;
aTitle.id = marker.feature.properties.id;
aTitle.onclick = function (e) {
    alert(marker.feature.properties.title);
    map.panTo(marker.getLatLng());
    marker.openPopup();
    return false;
};
var address = document.createElement("p");
address.innerHTML = marker.feature.properties.address + "<br />" + marker.feature.properties.city + ' ' + marker.feature.properties.state + "<hr />";

d.appendChild(aTitle);
d.appendChild(address);
    return d;
}

resultSet.appendChild(makeDiv());

//bind the same content to the info window.                
marker.bindPopup(makeDiv(), {
    autoPan: true,
    autoPanPadding: L.point(40, 40),
    closeButton: true
});
```